# Subgroup of finite index and direct product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

We consider $\mathbb{Z}_p$ the ring of $p$-adic, and integer $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{(p-1)\mathbb{Z}} \times \mathbb{Z}_p$, and we would like to find to subgroup $N$ of index $15$ over $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{(p-1)\mathbb{Z}} \times \mathbb{Z}_p$, or more precisely, just a condition on $p$ to have the existence of such a subgroup.

Actually, as I have the answer, I know that we should prove that :

$\exists r \in \mathbb{N} \quad 15 /p^r(p-1) \quad (*)$

which permits then to conclude, as we assume from the beginning of the exercise that $p<50$.

But I don't succeed to prove $(*)$. Actually, we know that the subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ of finite index are the $p^r\mathbb{Z}_p$.

But we don't know precisely (or in a simple way) the subgroup of $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{(p-1)\mathbb{Z}}\times \mathbb{Z}_p$, right ?
So, how to do to find $(*)$ ?

Thank you !

Comment: Does $\Bbb Z_p$ denote the (ring of) $p$-adic integers?

Comment: @AndreaMori Yes !

Comment: @ChocoSavour. The product above is presented as a group and thus each summand should be understood as a group. Use braces _{p-1} around 'p-1' after underscoring to write it as a subscript. $\Bbb Z_n$ is standard notation for the quotient ring $\frac{\Bbb Z}{n\Bbb Z}$ with $\Bbb Z_n^+$ its additive group. You can also use \frac{numerator}{denominator} in dollar signs to create a fraction.

Comment: @OliverKayende I have edited the post, I hope it's more clear. And when I write $Z_p$ it have to be understood as the ring of p-adic integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that every subgroup of $\Bbb Z_p$ of finite index has index a power of $p$.

If $H<\Bbb Z_p$ has finite index then it is open and as such must contain a basic open subgroup $p^r\Bbb Z_p$ for some $r>0$. But then there is a surjection
$$
\frac{\Bbb Z_p}{p^r\Bbb Z_p}\simeq\frac{\Bbb Z}{p^r\Bbb Z}\longrightarrow
\frac{\Bbb Z_p}{H}
$$
and we are done.

---

More generally, if $H$ is a subgroup of 
$\frac{\Bbb Z}{(p-1)\Bbb Z}\times\Bbb Z_p$ of finite index then it has to contain $\{\bar 0\}\times p^r\Bbb Z_p$ for some $r>0$.

Therefore, passing to the quotient, the subgroups $H<\frac{\Bbb Z}{(p-1)\Bbb Z}\times\Bbb Z_p$ of finite index are in one-to-one correspondence with the injective limit of the set of subgroups of
$$
K_r:=\frac{\Bbb Z}{(p-1)\Bbb Z}\times\frac{\Bbb Z_p}{p^r\Bbb Z_p}
\simeq\frac{\Bbb Z}{(p-1)\Bbb Z}\times\frac{\Bbb Z}{p^r\Bbb Z}.
$$
as $r$ varies.

But ${\rm gcd}(p^r,p-1)=1$ so that $K_r$ is actually cyclic of order $p^r(p-1)$ and thus a complete classification follows.

Comment: I don't understand something. Here we are considering $H$ a subgroup of $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{(p-1)\mathbb{Z}} \times \mathbb{Z}_p$, not only a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Ans as I don't think we can't decompose $H = H_1 \times H_2$ where $H_1$ is a subgroup of $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{(p-1)\mathbb{Z}}$ and $H_2$ a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: @ChocoSavour: the decomposition as product holds for subgroups of a product $C\times C^\prime$ of cyclic groups of coprime order. We can reduce to this case by the finite index assumption. See my edited answer.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the clarification. Just a last thing : when you say that $H$ must contain $\{1\} \times p^r \mathbb{Z}_p$, you are using that $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{(p-1)\mathbb{Z}}$ is torsion ? I mean, I prove this assertion but using in a crucial way that $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{(p-1)\mathbb{Z}}$ is torsion. Is it really necessary ? And I prove this assertion for $\{0\} \times \mathbb{Z}$ rather than $\{1\} \times \mathbb{Z}$, but maybe this is also right for $\{1\} \times \mathbb{Z}$...

Comment: @ChocoSavour : oops, sorry, I certainly meant $\{\bar0\}\times\cdots$. I guess I was thinking moltiplication ... I will correct the answer.

Comment: Okay thank you for everything !